# Parsing json for Nested Loop via PHP

Tags: php, mysql, json

I'm Parsing my json and I Want to Update my `awnser2` Column With `text` Object of `answer` Array, But my Output Is Last one of `Option` and `text`
I Want Just text Object, Can you Help Me To Take That?
This Is My json:

```
[{"id":"26","answer":[{"option":"3","text":"HIGH"}],"type":"3"},
{"id":"30","answer":[{"option":"3","text":"LOW"}],"type":"3"},
{"id":"31","answer":[{"option":"3","text":"LOW"}],"type":"3"}]
```

And This is My Code:

```
 <?php
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","arrayy");
    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
      echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
      }
    $sql="SELECT `survey_answers`,id_s FROM `user_survey_start`";
    if ($result=mysqli_query($con,$sql)){
         while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)){
            $json = $row[0];
            $jason_array  = json_decode($json,true);                        
            // awnser2  
             $answer = array(); 
                foreach ($jason_array as $data) {                   
                        foreach($data['answer'] as $ans){                                                       
                        echo $ans['text']."\n" ;                                                             
                        }                                           
                }
                $answers= implode(',',$ans);
                $sql3="update user_survey_start set awnser2='$answers' where id_s=".$row[1];//run update sql
                echo $sql3."<br>";
                mysqli_query($con,$sql3);                                                                           
          }
    }
    mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

And This Is My Output:

```
update user_survey_start set awnser2='3,HIGH' where id_s=1
```

But I Want to Have This One:

```
update user_survey_start set awnser2='HIGH,LOW,LOW' where id_s=1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$answers = array();
foreach ($jason_array as $data) {
    foreach($data['answer'] as $ans){
        $answers[] =$ans['text'] ;
    }
}
$answers= implode(',',$answers);
```

Comment: Just Updated First Row And in Secend row, I Have `Fatal error: [] operator not supported for strings in C:\wamp64\www\json\json.php on line 17`

Comment: It's fixed now.